# Replacing keywords in strings with sequence of symbols

Tags: python, string, class, replace

For an exercise, I have to create a simple profanity filter in order to learn about classes.

The filter gets initialized with a list of offensive keywords and a replacement template. Every occurrence of any of these words should be replaced with a string that is generated from the template. If the word size is shorter than the template, a substring should be used that starts from the beginning, for longer sizes, the template should be repeated as often as necessary.

The following are my results so far, with an example.

```
class ProfanityFilter:

    def __init__(self, keywords, template):
        self.__keywords = sorted(keywords, key=len, reverse=True)
        self.__template = template

    def filter(self, msg):

        def __replace_letters__(old_word, replace_str):
            replaced_word = ""
            old_index = 0
            replace_index = 0
            while old_index <= len(old_word):
                if replace_index == len(replace_str):
                    replace_index = 0
                else:
                    replaced_word += replace_str[replace_index]
                    replace_index += 1

                old_index += 1

            return replaced_word

        for keyword in self.__keywords:
            idx = 0
            while idx < len(msg):
                index_l = msg.lower().find(keyword.lower(), idx)
                if index_l == -1:
                    break
                msg = msg[:index_l] + __replace_letters__(keyword, self.__template) + msg[index_l + len(keyword):]
                idx = index_l + len(keyword)

        return msg


f = ProfanityFilter(["duck", "shot", "batch", "mastard"], "?#$")
offensive_msg = "this mastard shot my duck"
clean_msg = f.filter(offensive_msg)
print(clean_msg)  # should be: "this ?#$?#$? ?#$? my ?#$?"
```

The example should print:

```
this ?#$?#$? ?#$? my ?#$?
```

But it prints:

```
this ?#$?#$ ?#$? my ?#$?
```

For some reason it replaces the word "mastard" with 6 symbols instead of 7 (one for each letter). It works for the other keywords, why not for this one?

---

Also if you see anything else that seems off, feel free to tell me. Do keep in mind tho that I am a beginner and my "toolbox" is quite small atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the index logic.  You have two errors

1. Each time you reach the end of the replacement string, you *skip* a letter in the profanity:

   ```
       while old_index <= len(old_word):
           if replace_index == len(replace_str):
               replace_index = 0
               # You don't replace a letter; you just reset the new index, but ...
           else:
               replaced_word += replace_str[replace_index]
               replace_index += 1

           old_index += 1     # ... but you still advance the old index.
   ```

The reason you didn't notice this is that you have a *second* bug: you run your old_index from 0 *through* len(old_word), which is one *more* character than you started with.  For the canonical four-letter word (or words of 5 or 6 characters), the two errors cancel each other.  You didn't see this because you didn't test enough.  For instance, using:

```
f = ProfanityFilter(["StackOverflow", "PC"], "?#$")
offensive_msg = "StackOverflow on PC rulez!"
clean_msg = f.filter(offensive_msg)
```

Output:

```
?#$?#$?#$?# on ?#$ rulez!
```

The input words are 13 and 2 letters; the replacements are 11 and 3.

Fix those two errors: make `old_index` stay in bounds, and increment it only when you make a replacement.

```
        while old_index < len(old_word):
            if replace_index == len(replace_str):
                replace_index = 0
            else:
                replaced_word += replace_str[replace_index]
                replace_index += 1
                old_index += 1
```

---

Future improvements:

- Refactor this into a `for` loop.
- Don't reset your replace_index; in fact, get rid of it.  Simply use `old_index % len(replace_str)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this with a regular expression instead, since `re.sub()` has a handy API for dynamic replacements:

```py
import re


class ProfanityFilter:

    def __init__(self, keywords, template):
        # Build a regular expression that will match all of the profane words
        self.keyword_re = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(keyword) for keyword in keywords), re.I)
        self.template = template

    def _generate_replacement(self, word):
        l = len(word)
        # Figure out how many times to repeat the template
        repeats = (l // len(self.template)) + 1
        # Since we may end up with a string longer than the original,
        # slice to the correct length.
        return (self.template * repeats)[:l]


    def filter(self, msg):
        # Replace all occurrences of the regular expression with
        # a dynamically computed replacement value.
        return self.keyword_re.sub(
            lambda m: self._generate_replacement(m.group(0)),
            msg,
        )

f = ProfanityFilter(["duck", "shot", "batch", "mastard"], "?#$")
offensive_msg = "this mastard shot my duck"
print(f.filter(offensive_msg))
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't make a one-liner, but here's a terrible implementation anway.  *Don't do what VoNWooDSoN does*:

```
def replace(msg, keywords=["duck", "shot", "batch", "mastard"], template="?#$"):                                                                                                                                        
    for keyword in keywords * len(msg)):                                                                                                                                                   
        msg = (template*len(keyword))[:len(keyword)].join([msg[:msg.find(keyword)], msg[msg.find(keyword)+len(keyword):]]) if msg.find(keyword) > 0 else msg                                                            
    return msg                                                                                                                                                                                                          

offensive_msg = "this mastard shot my duck"                                                                                                                                                                             
clean_msg = replace(offensive_msg)                                                                                                                                                                                      

print(clean_msg)  # should be: "this ?#$?#$? ?#$? my ?#$?"                                                                                                                                                              
print(clean_msg=="this ?#$?#$? ?#$? my ?#$?")
```

*edit*
So, I guess that 3.8 has assignment expressions... So, but this'd be the one liner then (probably).

```
print ((lambda msg: [msg := (("?#$"*len(keyword))[:len(keyword)].join([msg[:msg.find(keyword)], msg[msg.find(keyword)+len(keyword):]]) if msg.find(keyword) > 0 else msg) for keyword in ["duck", "shot", "batch", "mastard"]])("this mastard shot my duck")[-1])
```